# Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups : The remote name could not be resolved:

Tags: term-store, 2016, hybrid-taxonomy

Trying to implement Hybrid Taxonomy between my local farm and SharePoint Online, I have to (or should) copy the local term store to my online site collection. For that one should use [Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt764067(v=office.16).aspx).

I already implemented Hybrid OneDrive & Sites, and Hybrid Search without errors and they are still working.

So I use this script (from the article [Configure hybrid SharePoint taxonomy (Preview)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-hybrid-SharePoint-taxonomy-Preview-dd287a75-09e0-403e-974e-4cc84a152815)):

```
$credential = Get-Credential

#Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups -LocalTermStoreName "<ManagedMetadataServiceApplicatoin>" -LocalSiteUrl "<OnPremisesSiteURL>" -RemoteSiteUrl "SharePointOnlineSiteURL" -GroupNames "Group1","Group2" -Credential $credential
Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups -LocalTermStoreName "Managed Metadata Service" -LocalSiteUrl "http://localRootSiteCollectionURL" -RemoteSiteUrl "https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/htt" -GroupNames "GroupNameInSiteCollectionTermStore" -Credential $credential
```

But after five minutes, the script fails

```
Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups : The remote name could not be resolved:
'tenantName.sharepoint.com'
At C:\script\Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups.ps1:4 char:1
+ Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups -LocalTermStoreName "Managed Metadata Service"
-LocalSiteU ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PTaxonomyGroups:
   SPCmdletMigrateSPTaxonomyGroups) [Copy-SPTaxonomyGroups], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Hybrid.Cmdlet.SPCm
   dletMigrateSPTaxonomyGroups
```

For the record, ULS doesn't show any records while running the script.

Comment: from this link, looks like it is time out issue may be you need to   "Re-instantiate the $spoContext object. When running a script in one go, this error shouldn’t pop because the Context will not prematurely expire." http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2012/06/07/scripting-sharepoint-online-with-powershell-using-client-object-model/